# MYSQL Group By same id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following 2 tables :

**TABLE 1:** user

```
   id   s_id   first_name   last_name
   ----------------------------------
   1     2     test          test
   2     2     hello         test
   3     2     now           hello
   4     1     john          smith
```

**TABLE 2:** section

```
   id    section_name
  -------------------
   1     first
   2     my section
   3     other section
```

based on the above two tables , I would like to write a MYSQL query to :

SELECT ALL from user table and GROUP THEM BY s_id ( SAME s_id) , how could I do that?

I would like to get all the s_id = 2 ALL grouped together as an array or object but controlled by s_id? so I would loop through the s_ids and print out the first and last name?

Here is an Example of the output:

```
$sections = array['my section'](array('first_name'=>'test' ,  'last_name'=>'test'),
                                array('first_name'=>'hello' ,  'last_name'=>'test'),
                                array('first_name'=>' now' ,  'last_name'=>'hello'))
```

thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're trying to get?

Comment: sure I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all the users with `s_id = 2` than:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` where `s_id` = 2 # this will give 3 users
```

otherwise if you group with `s_id` you'll get only one user for each section, and I think you don't want that

To show all, than you have to run query :

```
SELECT user.*, section.section_name FROM `user`
INNER JOIN section ON section.id = user.s_id
```

And trick it in PHP:

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        user.*, 
        section.section_name 
    FROM `user`
    INNER JOIN section 
        ON section.id = user.s_id
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$final_data = array();
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $final_data[$data['section_name']][] = $data;
}

print($final_data); // to see the result
```

Comment: but I dont want to specify a certain s_id = # , I want to grab all of them that got the same number so all the s_dis = 2 together and s_id = 1 together etc..

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
SELECT * FROM `user` GROUP BY `s_id`
```

But you have different question in your title and in your content.

So what you want in PHP is something like this:

```
while($row = your sql fetch)
{
    $array[$row['s_id']][] = array('first_name' => $row['first_name'], 'last_name' => $row['last_name']);
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I think `WHERE s_id = 2` should be added. OP: *"I would like to get all the `s_id = 2` ALL grouped together"* - but, I could be wrong.

Comment: I am edting this answer :)

Comment: so what would be the output for this one?

Comment: I am only getting on result back , not 3 rows?

Comment: Take a look at mysqli_fetch_array function in php. You need to cycle the query result and put them in an array with this php function, you do not need to group anything in sql, but only to use a where s_id=2

Comment: but again s_id = 2 is an example , I need all that share the same s_ids to be grouped together

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `mysqli_fetch_array` function in php.

You need to cycle the query result with this php function and put them in an array, you do not need to group anything in sql, but only:

`select * from user order by s_id`

In the php cycle you can populate your array as you need.